# Getting the worksheet to which the area belong to

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In VSTO, in developing an excel add-in, i've an excel area name, is it possible to get the worksheet it belong to? 
Is it also possible to get the worksheet that a cell belong to?

Comment: see the `.Parent` method. `?Range("A1").Parent.Name`. Not sure of exact syntax in VSTO but that is VBA equivalent.

Comment: How can i get the range from excel area name?

Comment: I am not well-versed in c#, but isn't an area just a range ... so, perhaps, something like this (again VBA) `?Range(Range("A1").Areas(1).Address).Parent.Name`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a range object just use `.parent` to get the worksheet. Then you can get the name of the worksheet or whatever else.

If you only have a range name as a string then you need to loop through the names in the workbook and worksheets looking for that name. Then use the refersTo property to get the address. Parse for the worksheet name.